# Command Line Interface: Choosing options from a list by character

Tags: java, loops, command-line-interface

How do I create an option menu in Java? This is as far as I know:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Mini {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Select an option: ");
    System.out.println(" A. Hat ");
    System.out.println(" B. Orange ");
    System.out.println(" C. Bounty ");   
    System.out.println(" D. Exit ");

    choice = enter.next(); /* <--what do i put because i use char? */
  }
}
```

and I have to use a a loop which is `do-while`. I'm confused if I use char.

Comment: Why do you think you need a `do while` loop?  I'm not saying that I disagree with using one.  I'm just curious as to where the requirement is coming from

Comment: it's just because i need to choose either a,b,c,d . if i use d the programs exit. i'm not sure if i should use do while or if then.. i'm sorry , i still am clueless here .

Comment: Do you know how to write a simple `while` or `do while`?

Answer (score 1):

1) First question: What do you get back from "enter.next()"?

A: Look at this tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

```
public class ScanXan {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner s = null;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt")));
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(s.next());
                ...
```

Output:

```
In
Xanadu
did
Kubla
Khan
A
stately
pleasure-dome
...
```

2) Second question: "I have to use loop which is do while..."

A: On other words, you have to loop *until some condition becomes true*.

For example, maybe you should keep asking "option" until the user selects "D. Exit".

```
public class Mini {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice;
    do {
      System.out.println("Select an option: ");
      System.out.println(" A. Hat ");
      ...
      System.out.println(" D. Exit ");
      choice = enter.next();
    } while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase ("d"));
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a validation `while` loop:

```
ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
options.add("A");
options.add("B");
options.add("C");
options.add("D");

String answer = "";

while(!options.contains(answer)) {
    System.out.println("Select an option: ");
    System.out.println(" A. Hat ");
    System.out.println(" B. Orange ");
    System.out.println(" C. Bounty ");   
    System.out.println(" D. Exit ");
    answer = enter.nextLine();
}

// answer is now either A, B, C, D
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Mini {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("A: Say something");
        System.out.println("B: Say something");
        System.out.println("C: Say something");
        System.out.println("D: Exit");

        while(true) {
            char input = in.next().toCharArray()[0];

            switch(input) {
            case 'A':
                System.out.println("Something");
                break;
            case 'B':
                System.out.println("Something");
                break;
            case 'C':
                System.out.println("Something");
                break;
            case 'D':
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```